# How to hide top part of hamburger menu in the XAML Navigation Sample?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

In the Windows UWP [XAML Navigation sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation) from git hub, how can you hide the very top part of the hamburger menu flyout that obscures the section title?

Currently it renders like this so there is a strip that hides the section title of the page.

[image]

How can I get it to look like this?  So the Section title is not obscured when I open the menu.

[image]

I tried playing with the z-index of the page header, but it had no effect.  The hamburger menu always renders over top everything else.

Comment: Do you realize this request is not so logical at a second look?  The distinction Header/Content is different on each page.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't understand the comment.  Take a look at Microsoft weather app for windows 10, or The Weather Channel app and you will see what I mean.  They are all using similar hamburger style menu but somehow they manage to supress the top part of it.  The header element is the same user control on each page, just the text value changes.

Comment: I didn't see your expected behavior in weather app, could you please show me a picture? The pane of splitview won't cover the title of this page when it is opened, do you want this?

Comment: The T10 Hamburger template might be a better demo, but what I tried to say is that it requires a convention between Shell and Details pages. In T10 this is implemented in the PageHeader control, with a little bug.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yes, weather app is more like using template 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the Microsoft weather app for windows 10, I think it's more like there is a region out of the `SplitView` control, which is to hold like "hamburger button", "back button", "commandbar", and "AutoSuggestBox".

Here I wrote a sample:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisiableConverter x:Key="visiblecvt" />
    <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="backgroundcvt" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding ElementName=listmenu, Path=SelectedItem.MenuText, Converter={StaticResource backgroundcvt}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="LightBlue" Click="Button_Click_Pane" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="24" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Click="Button_Click_Back" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE72B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="24" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="title" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=listmenu, Path=SelectedItem.MenuText}" />
        <CommandBar Grid.Column="3" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=title, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource visiblecvt}}">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Grid />
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" FontSize="24" Label="Accept" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" FontSize="24" Label="Cancel" />
        </CommandBar>
        <AutoSuggestBox Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsSuggestionListOpen="True" />
    </Grid>
    <SplitView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="RootSpiltView" OpenPaneLength="300" CompactPaneLength="50" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListView x:Name="listmenu" ItemsSource="{x:Bind menu}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuIcon}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuText}" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="splitviewContent" Navigated="splitviewContent_Navigated" />
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<NavigationItem> menu = new ObservableCollection<NavigationItem>();

public MainPage()

{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    menu.Clear();
    menu.Add(new NavigationItem { PageLink = typeof(Page1), MenuText = typeof(Page1).Name, MenuIcon = "\xE715" });
    menu.Add(new NavigationItem { PageLink = typeof(Page2), MenuText = typeof(Page2).Name, MenuIcon = "\xE716" });
    menu.Add(new NavigationItem { PageLink = typeof(Page3), MenuText = typeof(Page3).Name, MenuIcon = "\xE722" });
    menu.Add(new NavigationItem { PageLink = typeof(Page4), MenuText = typeof(Page4).Name, MenuIcon = "\xE72D" });
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listmenu.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void Button_Click_Pane(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootSpiltView.IsPaneOpen = !this.RootSpiltView.IsPaneOpen;
}

private void Button_Click_Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (splitviewContent.CanGoBack)
    {
        splitviewContent.GoBack();
    }
}

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var naviitem = listmenu.SelectedItem as NavigationItem;
    splitviewContent.Navigate(naviitem.PageLink);
}

private void splitviewContent_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var page = splitviewContent.CurrentSourcePageType.Name;
    switch (page)
    {
        case "Page1":
            listmenu.SelectedIndex = 0;
            break;

        case "Page2":
            listmenu.SelectedIndex = 1;
            break;

        case "Page3":
            listmenu.SelectedIndex = 2;
            break;

        case "Page4":
            listmenu.SelectedIndex = 3;
            break;
    }
}
```

The `NavigationItem` class and two converters:

```cs
public class NavigationItem
{
    public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public Type PageLink { get; set; }
}


public class BoolToVisiableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var text = (string)value;
        if (text == "Page1")
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var text = (string)value;
        if (text == "Page1")
        {
            return "#FFFFC0CB";
        }
        return "#00000000";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I didn't follow to the official XAML Navigation sample to wrote this code, here my sample renders like this:
[image]

@Henk Holterman's comment also makes sense. In the official sample, the title is part of the page content. For different page, the title may have different size. But in Weather app, the title is separated from the content, so it will be easy to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and your code produces the result I was looking for. I'm going to try and modify my code derived from XAML Navigation sample to match this layout.  But one question, since I am using an AppShell (root frame) which contains the splitview pane, would the strip to the right of the hamburger button (that contains title and other controls)  be placed on the frame (in AppShell) so it appears on every page?  I am able to use margin to shift splitview pane down by the height of the hamburger button so that it expands underneath it, leaving space above for the title and controls.

Comment: @erotavlas, if you put the hamburger button out of the splitview's pane, it will appears on every page. And by every page, I think you mean the pages which is put in the content of the splitview.